# Variar la opacidad cada vez que se mueva el ratón

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

cada vez que se mueva el ratón horizontalmente en una imagen, la opacidad tiene que cambiar, es decir, si se mueve a la derecha `10px` la opacidad aumenta `0.1`, y si es a la izquierda disminuye `0.1`. He usado el evento `mousemove`, para sacar el valor de la coordenada x. La pregunta es como puedo saber si aumenta o disminuye, tendría que tener el algún valor de x de la posición anterior para compararlo con la actual.

```
$("img").mousemove(function(event){
        // Posición absoluta horizontal del puntero menos la posición absoluta horizontal del elemento.
        var x = event.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    });
```

Comment: debes almacenar las posicones lo mas facil seria crear un arreglo `let postion=[0,0];` y ir actualizandolas cada vez que se mueve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asi como dices, hay que guardar la variable de la posición anterior, he ir actualizándola, cada vez que pide el valor.

Notas:

- Es necesario, iniciarlizar la variable `anterior`, y declararla fuera de la función.
- Para la respuesta que te di, no use jquery como tu, si no, un evento de html: [**onmousemove**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmousemove.asp)

```js
var anterior = 0;
var img = document.getElementById("img");
function aplicarOpacidad(event){
  var x = event.pageX - img.offsetLeft;
  
  img.style.opacity = x/img.offsetWidth;

  anterior = x;
};
```

```css
#img{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  display:block;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<img id="img" src="https://dummyimage.com/1080x1024/000/fff" onmousemove="aplicarOpacidad(event);"
/>
```